# Change gesture of Hyperion

Tags: android, hyperion

I and using Hyperion tool in my app. By default it gives details on shaking of device. For implementation referred this 
[link](https://github.com/willowtreeapps/Hyperion-Android)

I want to move this to any other gesture because I am already using shake for some other feature. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment there's no way to turn off the shake gesture to open the drawer, but you can get around this by setting the sensitivity to a really high value so it doesn't open on shake with

`Hyperion.setShakeGestureSensitivity(someHighValue)`

Next, you can implement a custom gesture that calls

`Hyperion.open()`

to open the drawer.

A new [issue](https://github.com/willowtreeapps/Hyperion-Android/issues/101) was just filed to allow disabling the shake gesture.